# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' in protein transformer

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, pytorch, tuples

I am following this [guide](https://github.com/facebookresearch/esm) to get some data from a protein file using the ESM-1b Transformer.

I have created a list of tuples out of a Fasta file that has some protein IDs and their sequences in each tuple.

```
parsed_list = [(k, v) for k, v in parsed_seqs.items()]
```

However, I ran out of RAM so I sliced the list in 650 samples:

```
new_list = parsed_list[:650]
```

When following the Guide I encounter the following error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' when trying to append the model tokens to another list. How should I be accessing the sliced list?

The code I have for now:

```
batch_labels, batch_strs, batch_tokens = batch_converter(new_list)

with torch.no_grad():
results = model(batch_tokens, return_contacts=True)
token_representations = results["representations"]

sequence_representations = []
for i, (_, seq) in enumerate(new_list): #Here is where I get the error

   sequence_representations.append(token_representations[i, 1 : len(seq) + 1].mean(0))
```